# How to rename file with array pattern new name in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, rename

I want to rename a some files. It depends on the array of string new name I have. I tried this, but the files is renaming all. My expectation, the file only rename 3 files, because I only has 3 array. Please help anyone can has idea. Thanks a lot.

```
$Names = @("Student", "Employee", "Married")

$DataFile = Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.txt #There are more than 10 files

foreach ($name in $Names)
{
     $DataFile | Rename-Item -NewName {"$name" + $_.Name} 
}
```

Comment: What are the names of the files you want to rename, and what is the desired output?

Comment: From looking at your code it seems that the reason for renaming all 10 files at once is because you pipe all files in $DataFile to Rename-Item. And because you have 3 elements in your $Names array there are a total of 30 file renames executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you will need to created an counter (`$i`) to index into the other array:

```
$Names = 'Student', 'Employee', 'Married'
$DataFile = Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.txt

$Names | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } {
    Rename-Item $DataFile[$i] ($_ + $DataFile[$i++].Name)
}
```

Note that the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) supports multiple script blocks:

> When you provide multiple script blocks to the Process parameter, the
> first script block is always mapped to the begin block. If there are
> only two script blocks, the second block is mapped to the process
> block. If there are three or more script blocks, first script block is
> always mapped to the begin block, the last block is mapped to the end
> block, and the blocks in between are all mapped to the process block.

Related: [`#13772` Automatic variable for the pipeline index](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to rename as many files as there are strings in your `$Names` array, you can do:

```
$Names = 'Student', 'Employee', 'Married'
$count = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.txt | Select-Object -First ($Names.Count) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}-{1}' -f $Names[$count++], $_.Name)
}
```